# restore database to server via create script

Tags: asp.net, sql, plesk

i have created my DB in plesk control panel then genarate script from local to run it in query to restore database , all work done , succesfuly connceted to DB , just now it cant find my tables and store procedures as i ran the query. what is the best way to upload my db ?

Comment: Create and restore are two very different operations - you cannot use the script for one of those operations for the other, I'm afraid.

Comment: i tested both of them , but i dont know why database will not created on the server !

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL databases Plesk has built-in support of phpMyAdmin. Just open it and choose to import DB in top menu. You may need to have phpMyAdmin installed locally to export local DB in a file. Alternatively I think you can use `mysqlbackup` tool or read phpMyAdmin documentation for more details about import file format.